# How can I add properties to an interface only when another property is 0

Tags: typescript, properties

i have an interface with 2 properties, a and b. b only exists when a is 0. how do i make this in typescript?

i got this far:

```
interface zero {
  a: 0,
  b: string
}

interface other {
  a: 1 // i want to say here 'every number except 0'
}

type test = zero | other;

declare let myVar: test;

if (myVar.a == 0) {
  myVar.a;
  myVar.b;
} else {
  myVar.a;
  myVar.b; // error, doesn't exist on 'other' (this is good!)
}
```

i took 1 as a number that is not 0, but i want this to work for every number that is not zero. (if this is not possible, i am fine as well with every non 0 positive integer)

Comment: TS doesn't have *negated types* as requested in [ms/TS#4196](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4196) so there's no specific type that corresponds to "all `number`s except `0`". (There is also no "positive integer" type).  So anything you do here would be a workaround.  For example you could use a type guard function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WzOZ2w).  Does that fully address your question (and I can write up an answer)?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"every number except 0" is not something Typescript can express at the moment.  You cannot declare a type that is an infinite set with a finite set removed from it.

You have the same problem with "non 0 positive integer". `number` is an infinite of all floating point numbers, and you can't pick an infinite subset of that, which means you can't pick numbers above zero, or even integers.

What you can do is declare some [type predicate functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to enforce this for you.

With these types:

```
interface Zero {
  a: 0,
  b: string
}

interface NotZero {
  a: number
}

type MaybeZero = Zero | NotZero
```

You can make a function like so:

```
function isZeroType(obj: MaybeZero): obj is Zero {
    return obj.a === 0
}
```

This will use runtime logic to check if a value can be casted to a specific type. In this case, if the `a` property is `0`, then we cast the input to the type `Zero`.

Which you would use like this:

```
declare const myVar: MaybeZero

if (isZeroType(myVar)) {
    myVar.b // fine
} else {
    myVar.b // error
}
```

The downside is that you must use these functions to narrow the types down.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&moduleResolution=99&preserveValueImports=false&isolatedModules=false&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=false&inlineSources=false&preserveWatchOutput=false&ts=4.6.4&ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=16&pc=1&preserveConstEnums=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgFrQPbIN4ChnJwBcyADADT7IBGJAzmFKAOa4C+uuoksiKAchjDooWPAWLIQAVwC21aO05gAngAcUAWTgqFIrAF40mZAB9kg4Zk4xpIBGGAYQyYHX0AVdRAAUGagBWJNq6EPoAlCT+Aa50xqI4VARQEGDSUC7RAHRwyAb5ZEq4ACYQCAA2cCnICM4MyLIqAGpVwTp61lwwyD5unt4+jS1Q4eGJBARDVVnUyAD0c8gwoBDsyBDldCjiE1NQM-OL0KJQ7EA)

Comment: yeah this works, but is not what i wanted.
i know it is not possible yet in typescript so i will have to wait